# recursion within a while loop

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

I am working on a leetcode problem [Reconstruct Itinerary](https://leetcode.com/problems/reconstruct-itinerary/), here is a very concise and accepted [answer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reconstruct-itinerary/discuss/741820/Python-Solution-or-Faster-than-99.53-Solutions-or-Memory-Usage-less-than-94.12-Solutions), which is also pasted below. I usually use recursion inside a for loop. I don't understand how exactly the `visit` works and why it outputs the reversed of the itinerary?  Could you please help me digest this code? I never used recursion in while loop before and it may have certain advantages over that in for loop.

```
class Solution:
    def findItinerary(self, tickets: List[List[str]]) -> List[str]:
        graph=collections.defaultdict(list)
        for edge in tickets:
            graph[edge[0]].append(edge[1])
        for i in graph:
            graph[i].sort(reverse=True)
        ans=[]

        def visit(current):
            while graph[current]:
                visit(graph[current].pop())
            ans.append(current)
            print(ans,current)  # This line added by me

        visit("JFK")
        return ans[::-1]
```

```
test case: 
    tickets = [["JFK","KUL"],["JFK","NRT"],["NRT","JFK"]]
output:
    ans[::-1] 
      ['JFK', 'NRT', 'JFK', 'KUL']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a tree where each node has a variable number of children. It could be 0 or 10,000 or any other non negative integer. The while loop is simply traversing each child node of node `current`. Observe that

```
while graph [current]
```

is true while the list is nonempty. Each element of the list at `current` is passed to the next level of recursion at the call site by popping the next element. Specifically

```
graph[current].pop()
```

simultaneously removes the element from the list and passes to the next level of recursion.

`ans` is in reverse order because all nodes are fully explored depth first before the current node is appended. You can see this by moving

```
ans.append(current)
```

To before the `while` loop.

Comment: by moving ```ans.append(current)``` to before the ```while``` loop, it gives an wrong answer. Could you please help further?

Comment: Right, I didn't mean to suggest that change is right. I only meant to give you an way to experiment with the order in which nodes are evaluated